# Merge into one rewrite rule: removal of trailing slashes, and www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How may I merge the removal of the trailing slash, and the www re-write rules?

```
RewriteEngine on

# prevent redirect loop on directory
DirectorySlash Off

# remove the trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# remove www. (generic method with HTTPS support)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# send everything (except existing files) to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I use to do this, but the removal of www. didn't support https:

```
# removes www. and trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: How many sites use this .htaccess?

Comment: It'll be apart of my boilerplate for new projects. So I want to keep the real domain name out of it. If that's what you're getting at.

Comment: Yes it was because if you did have the domain in the rewriterule it's easier to have the https work with www removal and trailing slash.

Comment: Oh, I suppose I could do that, but ideally I'd like the same rewrite file for localhost as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it this way to support https.

```
# removes www. and trailing slash and add https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To do all that in one rule and to make it work across the hostname (including localhost) you can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# hostname without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=host:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ http%1://%{ENV:host}/$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: I'm wanting to keep the RewriteRule's to a minimum though. In this case, just the two.

Comment: You shouldn't be over demanding with these rules. I can write a super complex rule to do all this in one rule but that won't be too readable. If you note there is only one last rule with `L` flag that ensures all of them are applied same pass of mod_rewrite. You can verify same by enabling `RewriteLog` if you want.

Comment: Check updated answer with a different approach for same problem.